# how does an app within a docker container access database hosted on another server which is in the same LAN

Tags: docker, lxc

I have an app within a docker container(ip: 172.17.42.1) on a server(ip: 192.168.1.8), and mysql database is on another server(ip: 192.108.1.19).

Comment: IMO in default configuration, you should be able to reach the database server from container.

Comment: @Jiri is correct, your container has network access. If the host can reach the database server, the container can as well (all local firewall rules aside)

Comment: @jiri thanks，guys。It failed last time, but just now it succeeded. I'll close the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to other docker containers using this command:

```
docker run -d -p [port:[port_no]--link [db_container] \
  -e DATABASE_URL=[web_address / ip] \ [image_name]
```